# Violation of PRIMARY KEY restriction - EF

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-6

I have a problem trying to update a record in the DB. I am using EF 6.2.0 in C # with .NET 4.7.2.

```
public abstract class BaseEntity { }

public abstract class Entity<T> : BaseEntity, IEntity<T>
{
    //public virtual T Id { get; set; }
}

public class Order : Entity<long>
{
    public long OrderID { get; set; }

    ...
    ...
    ...

    public StatusEnum Status { get; set; }

    public virtual Option Options { get; set; } = new Option();

    public virtual ICollection<OrderDetail> Details { get; set; } = new List<OrderDetail>();
}

public class Option : Entity<long>
{
    public long OptionID { get; set; }

    ...
    ...
    ...

    public virtual Order Order { get; set; }
}

public class OrderDetail
{
    public long OrderDetailID { get; set; }

    ...
    ...
    ...

    public virtual Order Order { get; set; }
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Option> Options { get; set; }

    ...
    ...
    ...

    modelBuilder.Entity<Order>()
        .HasOptional(x => x.Options)
        .WithRequired(x => x.Order);
}

using (var dbContext = new Context())
{
    var dbItem = dbContext.Orders.FirstOrDefault(...);
    if (dbItem != null)
    {
        dbItem.Status = StatusEnum.New;
        dbItem.Details.Add(orderDetail);
        dbContext.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

When I try to update I get the following error

```
"Violation of PRIMARY KEY restriction 'PK_dbo.Option' Unable to insert a key duplicated in object 'dbo.Option'. The value of the duplicate key is (1). \ R \ nIf finished the instruction. "
```

I do not understand why try to add another "Option" record with the same ID

Something I saw is that at the time of obtaining the database record, Options comes with the correct data, but OrderID is 0, when it would have to be 1 (In the DB it has a 1)

What is the problem? Thx!

Comment: Please add how exactly you are adding the record(s) to the context and the data they hold.

Comment: Hi. I add records as follows:

using (var dbContext = new Context ())
                         {
                             dbContext.Orders.Add (order);
                             dbContext.SaveChanges ();
                         }
If I do not change any property and try to save the data, I get the same error

Comment: Can you add that to the post, including what `order` has? (I don't care about the data, only the properties related to the Foreign Key issue)

Comment: I do not understand what you need, all the properties involved in the FK, they are in the original post, the ones that are missing are int, string properties that are not necessary, I think.

Comment: The problem is whether `option.Order` was loaded from the database or not. For example, this wouldn't happen if you assigned `option.OrderId` instead

Comment: Hello, I made an example to reproduce the error git clone https://avechuche@bitbucket.org/avechuche/ef.test.git

Answer (score 0):

You don't show that part of the code, but I assume that your `OrderDetail` entity has a dependant navigation property `Order`. Now when EF begins to track `OrderDetail` after you added it, EF by default recursively also marks all its related entities (unless already tracked) as added. In this case the state of `Options` are set to added via pricipal entity `Order`, so EF tries to insert them into database.
A solution to this would be either to:
1) not set/unset the `Order` principal navigation property, but set only the foreign key `OrderId`;
2) call update on principal entity `Order` (in this case be sure that your `Options` are tracked in the proper state or navigation property is unset or else you might end up with the same exact problem).

An excellent material on this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn166926.aspx

EDIT: apparently I'm blind because I missed the `OrderDetail` entity part. Well, at least I didn't miss my guess about the navigation property being there. :D